# Can't Install ardrone_autonomy

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently I am running an instance of **ROS Kinetic** on an **Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS** and  trying to install the package [ardrone-autonomy](http://ardrone-autonomy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html). However, the instructions on the linked page say that I can simply invoke the command:

```
apt-get install ros-kinetic-ardrone-autonomy
```

Is it because the package is not available on kinetic? Do I have to build from source using these instructions below?

```
$ cd ~/ros_catkin_ws
$ rosinstall_generator ros_desktop <package_name> --rosdistro kinetic --deps --wet-only --tar > kinetic-custom_ros.rosinstall
$ wstool merge -t src kinetic-custom_ros.rosinstall
$ wstool update -t src
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y -r --os=debian:jessie
$ sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/kinetic
```

If so, where exactly is the `/ros_catkin_ws` folder? I used `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full` install ROS, and the folder does not exist.

---

**EDIT**

Let me know what exactly I am doing wrong. When I invoke the command below, this is what I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ardrone-autonomy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-ardrone-autonomy
```

The output of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list` is:

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main
```

and `uname -a` is:

```
Linux rasp 4.1.19-v7+ #858 SMP Tue Mar 15 15:56:00 GMT 2016 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252390/can%27t-install-ardrone_autonomy/) by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2017-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tl;dr: OP is running 16.04 MATE LTS on an ARM device, and `ardrone_autonomy` has not been released for that platform (at least not as of 2017-01-23).

---

You don't tell us what is actually going wrong. Does `apt-get` give you an error when you invoke it? If so: please include that in your post.

Also: looking at [ros_kinetic_default.html?q=ardrone](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=ardrone) and [wiki/ardrone_autonomy](http://wiki.ros.org/ardrone_autonomy) it looks like `ardrone_autonomy` is released in Kinetic, so `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ardrone-autonomy` should work.

---

Edit: I've just tested the following on a Docker container running Mate 16.04 x64 (after having setup ROS Kinetic according to the instructions on [the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu)):

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ardrone-autonomy
```

This results in the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  graphviz libcdt5 libcgraph6 libgvc6 libgvpr2 libpathplan4 libyaml-cpp-dev libyaml-cpp0.5v5
  ros-kinetic-camera-calibration-parsers ros-kinetic-camera-info-manager ros-kinetic-image-transport
  ros-kinetic-tf ros-kinetic-tf2 ros-kinetic-tf2-msgs ros-kinetic-tf2-py ros-kinetic-tf2-ros
Suggested packages:
  gsfonts graphviz-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  graphviz libcdt5 libcgraph6 libgvc6 libgvpr2 libpathplan4 libyaml-cpp-dev libyaml-cpp0.5v5
  ros-kinetic-ardrone-autonomy ros-kinetic-camera-calibration-parsers ros-kinetic-camera-info-manager
  ros-kinetic-image-transport ros-kinetic-tf ros-kinetic-tf2 ros-kinetic-tf2-msgs ros-kinetic-tf2-py
  ros-kinetic-tf2-ros
0 upgraded, 17 newly installed, 0 to remove and 76 not upgraded.
Need to get 3865 kB of archives.
After this operation, 25.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
```

It would seem that the problem is really at your end, as `ardrone_autonomy` is released for Kinetic and I can install it locally on a system similar to yours.

Can you try the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ardrone-autonomy
```

Please copy and paste these lines, one at a time, in a terminal, then press enter.

If that still doesn't work, see if cleaning the `apt` indices (see [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/630985) for steps), updating and trying to install again works.

---

Edit2:

> and `uname -a` is:

> ```
> Linux rasp 4.1.19-v7+ #858 SMP Tue Mar 15 15:56:00 GMT 2016 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
> ```

This is partly my fault, as I should have asked about what system / platform you are using, but `ardrone_autonomy` is not released on ARM platforms (see [status_page/ros_kinetic_uxhf.html?q=ardrone](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_uxhf.html?q=ardrone)). If you'd checked the [ros_kinetic_default.html?q=ardrone](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=ardrone) and [wiki/ardrone_autonomy](http://wiki.ros.org/ardrone_autonomy) links I included earlier, you'd seen that those all mention `x32`, `x64`, `i386` and `amd64` only. No mention of `arm` anywhere.

That is the reason why `apt-get` can't find `ros-kinetic-ardrone-autonomy`.

If you want to use that package on ARM, you'll have to build from sources (that is the second exception to the "never build from sources, unless you have to" mantra: you'll have to if a package has not been released for your target platform.

PS: in future question, *please* include what CPU architecture / platform you are trying to run things on, as it would have saved us both (and future readers) a lot of time.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-19**:
Check out the edit I made above.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-19**:
And how did you install ROS? Can you install any ROS package using `apt-get`?

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-19**:
Can you give me an example of a package that I can use, that's not in the `ros-kinetic-desktop-full` package and available for kinetic?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-19**:\

> that's not in the `ros-kinetic-desktop-full` package and available for kinetic

so you have installed the `ros-kinetic-desktop-full` package using `apt-get`?

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-19**:
Yes, as mentioned in the question, I did use `sudo apt-get ros-kinetic-desktop-full` to install my ROS

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-19**:
Mate 16.04 is essentially a regular Ubuntu release, so all Kinetic packages that are available for Ubuntu Xenial should be available for Mate. According to all the information we have, `ardrone_autonomy` is availale no kinetic, so it should work. Can you try a `sudo apt-get update`?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-19**:
And no: you should not build Kinetic from source. It wouldn't make sense to build an entire ROS distribution from sources (and with the Debian Jessie instructions) for just a single pkg. If at all, you could build `ardrone_autonomy` from sources, but I'd try to resolve the `apt` thing first.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-19**:
so I just installed `ros-kinetic-joy` with the command `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-joy`

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-23**:
I just tried `sudo apt-update`, `sudo apt-upgrade` and `sudo apt-get clean`. Should I go ahead and install `ardrone-autonomy` using what was given as an answer in [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/252478/how-to-build-a-package-from-source-on-ubuntu-mate-1604-lts-and-ros-kinetic/) question?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-23**:
And after all the `apt-get` commands, did you try installing again (using `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ardrone-autonomy`)?

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-23**:
Yes I did, and it still gives me the same error.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-23**:
So should I go ahead with the answer on that question?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-23**:
What is the output of `apt-cache search ardrone`?

And can you please be a little patient? Building from source should *always* be your last resort, *unless* you want to actually edit a pkg's sources.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-23**:
I get nothing when I invoke `apt-cache search ardrone`

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-23**:
Sure, as long as we can zero in on the problem soon. I have to progress along this project soon.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-23**:
If you don't get any output from `apt-cache`, something is not configured correctly. Please *edit* your original post and include the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list` and the output of `uname -a`.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-23**:
Just made the edits. Take a look at them.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-23**:
So would I follow the instructions on the other question to install this package then?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-23**:
Yes. In this case it would be acceptable to build from source. No guarantees that it will work though.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-23**:
Alright, will try that now.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-23**:
Should we clean up this comments section?

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-23**:
Also I have posted a [new](http://answers.ros.org/question/252786/trying-to-build-ardrone_autonomy-from-source-on-my-ubuntu-mate-and-failing/) question here related to this topic.